# Spark on YARN and spark-bigquery connector

Tags: scala, apache-spark, google-bigquery, spark-streaming, hadoop-yarn

I have developed a Scala Spark application for streaming data directly into Google BigQuery, using the spark-bigquery connector by Spotify.

Locally it works correctly, I have configured my application as described here https://github.com/spotify/spark-bigquery

```
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(120))
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.setGcpJsonKeyFile("/opt/keyfile.json")
sqlContext.setBigQueryProjectId("projectid")
sqlContext.setBigQueryGcsBucket("gcsbucketname")
sqlContext.setBigQueryDatasetLocation("US")
```

but when I submit the application on my Spark on YARN cluster the job fails looking for GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable...

```
The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.
```

I set the variable as OS env var for root user to the .json file containing the credentials required, but it still fails.

I have also tried with the following line

```
System.setProperty("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", "/opt/keyfile.json")
```

without success.

Any idea on what I'm missing?

Thank you,

Leonardo

Comment: can you share some code snippets?

Comment: I have added some code, please let me know if you need more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the documentation suggests:
"Environment variables need to be set using the spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName] property in your conf/spark-defaults.conf file.
Environment variables that are set in spark-env.sh will not be reflected in the YARN Application Master process in cluster mode."

Comment: If you don't want to edit global conf files, this can be set also when submitting the job like this (if running on YARN):

`spark-sumbit --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/opt/keyfile.json .. jar`